# SQL Server: error could not find type in assembly during dll trigger creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sqlclr

In Microsoft SQL Server, I want to call a dll assembly as a trigger

This is my C# code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WriteTimeInfile
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\Vivien\Desktop\date.txt",
                   DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my properties panel:

[image]

Then I create the assembly in SQL Server, it seems to work and create an assembly:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY triggertest
FROM 'C:\Users\Vivien\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WriteTimeInfile\WriteTimeInfile\bin\Release\WriteTimeInfile.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
```

But when I try to create the trigger, i try to do like it is explained in this [link](http://www.codepal.co.uk/show/Could_not_find_type_in_assembly):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tri_Publishes_clr
ON STATION
FOR INSERT
AS EXTERNAL NAME triggertest.[WriteTimeInfile.WriteTimeInfile.Program].Main
```

I get an error

> Could not find Type 'WriteTimeInfile.WriteTimeInfile.Program' in assembly 'WriteTimeInfile'.

Nothing works

Could you help me please?

Comment: Check your project settings http://www.codepal.co.uk/show/Could_not_find_type_in_assembly

Comment: it does not work but thank you for link

Comment: `PERMISSION_SET = SAFE` and writing to a file won't work either.

Comment: you are right  I was just realising that problem , just as my code canot work because it  has no System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission

Comment: @MartinSmith and Vivien: Correct, `SAFE` won't work here. Please see the two notes I just added to the my answer (under the line).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not create a SQLCLR Trigger in your .NET code. This signature:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
```

is for a Console App. You need to use the proper declaration for a SQLCLR object, which include using the `SqlTrigger` attribute.

```cs
[SqlTrigger(Name = "trigger_name", Target = "[schema].[table]",
            Event = "FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE")]  
public static void TriggerName()
{
}
```

For more info on SQLCLR Triggers, please see the MSDN page for [CLR Triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131093.aspx).

For more info on working with SQLCLR in general, please see the series I am writing on SQL Server Central (free registration is required to read content on that site): [Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/).

---

PLEASE NOTE: *IF* the only reason for doing a SQLCLR Trigger is to use `File.AppendAllText`, then you might be better off creating a SQLCLR UDF / Scalar Function to do the same thing and then using that Function in a regular T-SQL Trigger.

**ALSO**, and this is very important, since you are doing file system related functionality, your Assembly will need to be set to `EXTERNAL_ACCESS`. Please do *not* accomplish this by setting the Database to `TRUSTWORTHY ON`. Please sign the Assembly (protect it with a password), then create an Asymmetric Key from that Assembly in `master`, then create a Login based on that Asymmetric Key, and then grant that Key-based Login `EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY`. You will see this approach in the various articles I wrote in the above mentioned "Stairway to SQLCLR" series.